# Get PSQL Exception when passing List<String> as a Query parameter in "IN" clause using JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am creating the `Spring Boot` application with a `PostgreSQL` database. and I am using `JDBCTemplate` to perform DB operations. as per my requirement, I want a `count` of the `row` from `CONTRACT_VIEW_2` table where the value of `LICENSE_PLATE = "xxxxxx"` and `ZONE_CODE is IN ("x","y","z")` but I am getting PSQL Exception.

I tried using MapSQLParameterSource but still, I facing the issue.

```
@Override
public Integer getAllZoneForLp(String lp,List<String> zones) {
  MapSqlParameterSource zoneIds = new MapSqlParameterSource();
  zoneIds.addValue("zoneIds",zones);
  String sql = "select " +
        "count(*) " +
        "from contract_view_2 " +
        "where license_plate = ? and zone_code IN (?)";
  return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,Integer.class,lp,zoneIds);
}
```

I expect the `row count` in the result but I am getting `PSQL Exception`. I am attaching the image of the exception which I am getting.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with yours is you have added `Namedparameter` to  `JdbcTemplate`.

So in case you are using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

```java
@Override
public Integer getAllZoneForLp(String lp,List<String> zones) {
  MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
  parameters.addValue("lp", lp);
  parameters.addValue("zoneIds",zones);
  String sql = "select " +
        "count(*) " +
        "from contract_view_2 " +
        "where license_plate = :lp and zone_code IN (:zoneIds)";
  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

  return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, parameters, Integer.class);
}
```

In case you want to use `jdbcTemplate`

```
@Override
public Integer getAllZoneForLp(String lp,List<String> zones) {
  String sql = "select " +
        "count(*) " +
        "from contract_view_2 " +
        "where license_plate = ? and zone_code IN (?)";

  return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class, new Object[] { lp, zones}); 
}
```

Go with `NameParameterJdbcTemplate` so that you won't miss any params.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your query to

```
  String sql = "select " +
        "count(*) " +
        "from contract_view_2 " +
        "where license_plate = ? and zone_code IN (:zoneIds)";
```

**Changes: changed ? to :zoneIds**

Line `zoneIds.addValue("zoneIds",zones);` is using named parameter to bind it.